# Send mail from godaddy server

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

```
$config = array(
    'protocol' => 'smtp',
    'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
    'smtp_port' => 465,
    'smtp_user' =>'abc@gmail.com',
    'smtp_pass' => 'abc',
    'mailtype' => 'html',
    'charset' => 'iso-8859-1',
    'wordwrap' => TRUE
     );
    $this->load->library('email',$config);
    $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
    $this->email->from($email,$name);
    $this->email->to('abc@gmail.com');
    $this->email->subject('ENQUERY');
    $this->email->message($string);
    $this->email->send();
```

this code is not working in godaddy server.
error:
Severity: Warning

Message: fsockopen(): unable to connect to ssl://smtp.googlemail.com:465 (Connection refused)

Answer (score 0):

Your SSl port may be closed in godaddy shared hosting. Check with following code

```
$fp = fsockopen("smtp.gmail.com", 465, &$errno, &$errstr, 10); 
if (!$fp)
    echo "smtp.gmail.com 465 is not working  -  $errstr   ($errno)";
else
    echo "smtp.gmail.com 465 is  working";
```

Comment: smtp.gmail.com 465 is not working - Connection refused (111)

Comment: you cannot send emails from this port on godaddy shared server. GoDaddy has ports 465 & 587 blocked and will not open them. You must send admin messages and form email directly to a GoDaddy hosted email account or forwarder.

Comment: can you please explain???? though i tried from port 25 using name@mydomen.com smtp_user... but the same error still...

Comment: You can only use godaddy email server or for a domain hosted on godaddy change 'smtp_host' => 'localhost' and than try sending the mail from the same domain